# Linux: cuda (pytorch) does not allocate available vram

Tags: linux, memory, nvidia, outofmemoryerror, cuda

[image]

I am trying out pixray/clipit but cuda fails to allocate the remaining 1GiB  of my graphics card.
My graphics card is "Nvidia GTX 1660 super" which has the same amount of RAM as the "Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti" which belongs to somebody I know - and it works just fine there, probably using Windows though.

My system is 64 bit, `Linux Manjaro-Desktop2 5.15.60-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 11 13:14:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

CUDA:

[image]

Why does PyTorch (CUDA) crash even there's 1GiB of available vram?
Here you can find information about my graphics card: https://www.nvidia.com/de-de/geforce/graphics-cards/compare/?section=compare-16